# Migrate MySQL database to Oracle 11g with SQL Developer 3

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, data-migration, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to migrate a sample database from mysql to Oracle 11g using SQL developer. I go through some online tutorial and follow each steps but I don't know why there is no data show up in the target database.

Here is what I did:

1. Connect to MySQL(connection name "MySQL") using SQL Developer with JConnector, log on as root.
2. Create a empty schema for "Repository" during migration named "TEMPBUFFER"
3. Create a target schema for holding the data in Oracle, named "DEVELOPER"
4. Follow migration wizard:

> Migration Repository = TEMPBUFFER
>   Third party database for migration = MySQL
>   Target schema in Oracle = DEVELOPER
>   Only one database called "classmodels" is chosen to be immigrated from MySQL

So here are my questions:

1. On top of everything, why there is no table/data show up on DEVELOPER schema, how to fix it?
2. What is a Migration Repository and why we need it? It seems hold a few tables with config information, so is it very common we should use the target schema as Migration Repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm struggling with same issue. Did you find what's wrong? if you do, please share it.

Answer (score 3):

i know this is old but the last step is to do copy to oracle when right click the tables on the source scheme

step 27 in this tut
http://taliphakanozturken.wordpress.com/tag/db-migration-using-sql-developer/